# Cannot connect to binance testnet API

Tags: node.js, binance

i trying to connect to the binance testnet API. Unfortunetaly it does not seem to work, it says "'Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.'"

The non-testnet works fine, but as soon as i put the testnet url into `baseURL` it doesnt work. what i am doing wrong?

```
const client = new Spot(apiKey, apiSecret, {
  baseURL: "https://testnet.binance.vision"
});
// Get account information
client
  .account()
  .then(response => client.logger.log(response.data))
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: Are you using the same credentials for the testnet as for the production API? Or have you registered a different account (and set up a different API credentials) on the testnet site?